# SOLVED Raspberry Pi Zero GPIO pin not detecting Input

Tags: gpio, pi-zero-w, rpi.gpio, electronics

So I am using a Raspberry Pi Zero to detect the signal from this NPN Inductive proximity sensor (its input supply range is 6 to 36V and the signal pin to output the same amount of voltage which we give as input).

The input supply of the proximity sensor is 6 volts from a step-up converter. Its output is also 6V, which is connected to a voltage divider made from resistors to bring it down to around 3V.

This 3V is then connected to a GPIO pin on the Raspberry Pi Zero, but it just doesn't detect it. The pin stays on "low" no matter what.

This 3V is then connected to a GPIO pin on the Raspberry pi zero but it just doesn't detect it. The pin stays on low no matter what.

The code I am using is this

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

p = 7

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(p,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

print(GPIO.input(p))

while True:
    #print(GPIO.input(p))
    if GPIO.input(p) == 1:
        print('Input was HIGH')
    else:
        pass
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

I've tried changing the GPIO pin multiple times, but no result. I've also connected a 4x4 matrix keyboard and an LCD to the pi. Those work fine, only this Inductive proximity sensor is creating issues.

Please help. Any help is appreciated, I really need to complete this client's project om time.

Comment: Need a clear photo showing the connections made.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved now. The issue was that the step-up converter was unable to provide enough current. So I used another device for powering it and it works.
Peace!

Comment: Congrats, but it seems a *bit odd* that simply connecting the GPIO pin to the sensor would add enough loading on the 6V supply to reduce its output voltage.